# Adding backup functionality to an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'd like to provide backup functionality to my app, it's a financial app.

I'm not really sure what type to provide, dropbox or wifi, or something different?

I just want to provide something simple / quick to develop, so users can import / export aka restore / backup.

Any suggestions / thoughts ?

Comment: I think that all depends on how you are saving their data in the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly the quickest way is to use iCloud - that said, Apple strongly discourage you from using iCloud in apps to store sensitive data. If your data is very sensitive (ie, financial), it sounds like you might need to look into some kind of secure system. Plain e-mail as suggested may not be the best solution.

Comment: I'm really looking for advice on an approach to development or an article. I don't think iCloud will be flexible enough

Answer (score -1):

From what I understand you want your users to be able to backup their data from within your application.  If this is correct then you can create a CSV file and then send it to either your server to store, or maybe allow your users to email themselves the file (as long as you allow some sort of method to import CSV files - preferably if you stored this on your own servers and database for the user).

Here is a good link for converting your users data to a CSV file.
[How to convert the NSMutableArray to CSV file on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436959/how-to-convert-the-nsmutablearray-to-csv-file-on-iphone)

Comment: Id need something more comprehensive and some way of encoding the data