# Convert plist to CSV file?

Tags: iphone, database, csv, plist

I have a .plist file containing array and dictionaries.  I want to convert this into a CSV file so I can then upload this online to a database.  Does anyone know of a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dave DeLong has written a CSV parser which will help you accomplish this task, you can get more info on this answer he has posted in this question.. [How to convert the NSMutableArray to CSV file on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436959/how-to-convert-the-nsmutablearray-to-csv-file-on-iphone)

Answer (score 4):

Look the following code

```
  NSString* plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSArray *commentArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

    NSMutableString *mainString=[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@""];
    for(int i=0;i<[commentArray count];i++ ) {
        NSString *string=[[commentArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"cmtName"]; 
        string=[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\"\""];
        [mainString appendFormat:@"\"%@\"",string];

        string=[[commentArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"cmtDesc"];  
        string=[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\"\""];
        [mainString appendFormat:@",\"%@\"",string];

        string=[[commentArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"cmtType"];
        string=[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\"\""];
        [mainString appendFormat:@",\"%@\"",string];

        [mainString appendFormat:@",\"%@\"",string];
        [mainString appendFormat:@"\n"];
     }


NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,  NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectoryPath  stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Docment.conf"];


NSData* settingsData;
settingsData = [mainString dataUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];

if ([settingsData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES])
    NSLog(@"writeok");
```

You can also use https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser for generating CSV.